# Play reverse routing - getting absolute url

Tags: playframework-2.2

How can I get the absolute URL in play 2.2 scala when doing the following:

```
val promoLink = routes.Promotions.promotionsCategory(DOCID, slug)


//routes file

GET /promotions/:DOCID:/slug     controllers.Promotions.promoCat(DOCID, slug)
```

As it stands I get a "found : play.api.mvc.Call" type mismatch on expecting a string

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your promoLink should be a `String` containing an URL? Your question sounds a bit unclear.

If so then you probably need this:

```
val promoLink = routes.Promotions.promotionsCategory(DOCID, slug).absoluteURL(false)(request)
```

`false` in the `.absoluteURL(false)` stands for the `isSecure` parameter which will give you `http` or `https` url.

If you have an implicit request in scope you may omit the last `(request)` part

Comment: thanks, however it appears it is actually absoluteURL (uppercase).