# How to get absolute URL of action in controller via Scala Routing DSL?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

Initially, I used the default routing approach by specifying my routes in the `conf` directory.

Now I made the switch to Play's routing DSL and my router looks as follows:

```
package controllers.app.api

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._

class UserRouter @Inject()(controller: UserController) extends SimpleRouter {

  val prefix = "/v1/users"

  override def routes: Routes = {

    case POST(p"/") =>
      controller.doStuff()

  }

}
```

My question is, how can I get the absolute URL of `controller.doStuff()`? Before making the switch, I used the following code:

```
controllers.app.api.routes.UserController.doStuff().absoluteURL()
```

But now I always get the following error:

```
object routes is not a member of package controllers.app.api
```

Comment: I believe you just need to do `routes.UserController.doStuff().absoluteURL()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play reverse routing - getting absolute url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536327/play-reverse-routing-getting-absolute-url)

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet No, I am dealing with a multi-module project here, aggregating reverse routes among multiple modules to prevent circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The general case

```
controllers.app.api.routes.UserController.doStuff().absoluteURL()
```

If UserController is in the same package as the caller then

```
routes.UserController.doStuff().absoluteURL()
```

remember, Request or RequestHeader must be in the implicit scope

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, this is exactly how I tried it (please read my question). I am trying to use reverse routing with Play's Routing DSL in a multi-module Play project. Apparently, there's no reverse routing support for he routing DSL.